# PL/SQL numeric value or error: confusion with functions and procedures (Oracle PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, runtime-error

I previously asked a question in stackoverflow regarding a certain function that I was having a hard time with and I found the answer when I saw the RETURN statement missing.

Now, I am dealing with a procedure that calls for the input text letters to be converted to UPPER if in the LOWER case and vice versa.

e.g IF I put in 'AbC' it should return 'aBc'

So far this is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Opposite_Case (p_string IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
       var_string VARCHAR2(20);
       var_contain VARCHAR2(20);
       i NUMBER;
BEGIN

       var_string:=substr(Opposite_Case.p_string,i,1);
       var_contain:= var_string || var_contain;
       FOR i in 1.. length(var_string) 
         LOOP
           BEGIN
               IF var_string IN ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') THEN
               SELECT LOWER(var_string) INTO var_contain FROM dual;
               ELSE
               SELECT UPPER(var_string) INTO var_contain FROM dual;
               END IF;
           END;    
         END LOOP;

END;
/
```

BUT the following error is returned:

```
EXECUTE Opposite_Case('AbC')
begin Opposite_Case('AbC'); end;
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OPPOSITE_CASE", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1

Thanks in advance.
```

PS. This is just my 3rd day with a PL/SQL language so please bear with me.

EDIT: I got it to work finally thanks to @Satya's help. Now I get to convert them like it should but how do I output my selects in one line though?

I'm almost there. Appreciate the help a lot from this community!!

What I have so far:

```
SQL> EXECUTE Opposite_Case('AbC')
A
b
C
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: change this line var_string:=substr(Opposite_Case.p_string,i,1); to  var_string:=substr(p_string,i,1);  and it should work  . Also just curious about FOR i in 1.. length(var_string)  , shouldn't this be FOR i in 1..length(var_string)

Comment: @Satya - thanks for fixing it.

I tried the code now but it doesn't give me the output that I want though (it displays blanks). Care to lend an extra hand still? The logic is very fuzzy to me. Tried to remove var_contain this time.

I really appreciate it.

Comment: Functions like UPPER, LOWER, TRANSLATE etc. are valid PL/SQL functions as well, you don't need to execute queries to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the [TRANSLATE function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions204.htm#i1501659). To use it to switch the case of the characters in your string you'd do something like the following:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('AbC',
                 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
  FROM DUAL;
```

which should return 'aBc'.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0077e/2)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: WOW this is great. I'll try this one out. Thank you!

But the thing is we might be required to use UPPER or LOWER case. I tried my code and it turns out the logic of my code was bad. Care to give me a clue at the very least? Will really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3873164 - before the loop you set `var_string` to the first character of the string. Inside the loop you never change it. You might want to look into that. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer! Thanks guys! (without `TRANSLATE` though)!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Opposite_Case (p_string IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
   var_string VARCHAR2(20);
   var_contain VARCHAR2(20);
   i NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR i in 1.. length(p_string) 
     LOOP
       BEGIN
         var_string:=substr(p_string,i,1);
         var_contain:= var_string;
           IF var_string IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z') THEN
           SELECT LOWER(var_string) INTO var_contain FROM dual;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(var_contain);
           ELSE
           SELECT UPPER(var_string) INTO var_contain FROM dual;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(var_contain);
           END IF;

       END;
     END LOOP;
    dbms_output.new_line;
END;
/
```